# Sorting an Array of Pointers in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, bubble-sort

I'm trying to sort an array of pointers according to the values in an array, leaving the original dataset alone. However, when I output the pointer array and then the data array, they both have the same sorted values. How can I sort the array of pointers without changing `data[]`?

I think what's happening is that the values that `arrptr[]` is pointing to are being sorted and in turn the `data[]` array is somehow being messed up. I tried using a pointer to a pointer but only got errors (`int**` to `int*` conversion).

For reference, this is how I assigned the pointer array to the data array:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
 {
     ReadingFile >> num1;
         
     data[i] = num1;

     ptrarr[i] = &data[i];
 }
```

These are the display functions that output the same exact sorted result:

```
static void DisplayArray(int* ptrarr[], int size)
{
    cout << "The Pointer Array of sorted pointer elements:\n";
    
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        cout << *ptrarr[i] << "     ";   //gives same result as DisplayData
    }
    
    cout << endl;

    return;
}

static void DisplayData(int data[], int size)
{
    cout << "Data Array elements are:\n";

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        cout << data[i] << "     ";
    }

    cout << endl;

    return;
}
```

Here are my sorting functions:

```
static void SwapIntPtr(int* a, int* b)
{
int temp = *a;
*a = *b;
*b = temp;

    return;

}
static void Sorting(int* ptrarr[], int size)
{

        for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < size - i - 1; j++)
            {
                if (*ptrarr[j] > *ptrarr[j + 1])
                {
                    SwapIntPtr(ptrarr[j], ptrarr[j + 1]);
                }
            }
        }
        
        return;

}
```

It's hard for me to see the issue as everything looks like it should work. However, I'm hoping a fresh set of eyes could help me see the problem.

Comment: Your swap function is not changing the POINTERS.  It's changing the things the pointers POINT at.  Your Swap function needs to accept `int ** a` and `int ** b`.

Comment: You can observe the flaw, here, very easily. Just ask yourself: what is your swap function swapping. It gets a pair of pointers to `int`s, right? And it's swapping the `int`s, right? Well, if your goal is to sort the pointers, which involves swapping the pointers, then swapping the `int`s, instead would be described by Mr. Spock as "highly illogical".

Comment: Is this a school or similar assignment or exercise? Because if it's not then you should just use [`std::sort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) with a suitable [lambda](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) for the comprison function.

Comment: Just one line `int temp = *a;` shows that you are sorting integers, not pointers.

Comment: Minor point: `ReadingFile >> data[i]` will work just fine; there's no need for that `num1` intermediate variable.

Comment: Why are you even sorting `int*`? Sorting ints directly would have been more easy, there is no need for pointers here. Then you use "C" style arrays, where `std::span` (C++20) is probably the better choice, adn finally as said just use std::sort. If someone is teaching you C++ it looks like that someone is teaching you a somewhat dated version of C++. Note for arrays it is more idiomatic to use `std::vector<int>`.

Comment: You would have avoided this problem if you used an array of `int const*`.  That prevents you changing the pointed-to values through those pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SwapIntPtr` swaps the values, not the pointers. Just use `std::swap` or if you really need to implement your own swap:

```
static void SwapIntPtr(int*& a, int*& b)
{
  int* temp = a;
  a = b;
  b = temp;
}
```

Note that the pointers need to be passed by reference in order for the swap function to be able to modify them.

It would be simpler to use `std::sort`:

```
std::sort(ptrarr, ptrarr + size, [](int* a, int* b) { return *a < *b; });
```

Answer (score 0):

As I said, you're sorting the things the pointers point at, not the pointers themselves.  This works:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

static void DisplayArray(int* ptrarr[], int size)
{
    cout << "The Pointer Array of sorted pointer elements:\n";
    
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        cout << *ptrarr[i] << "     ";   //gives same result as DisplayData
    }
    
    cout << endl;

    return;
}

static void DisplayData(int data[], int size)
{
    cout << "Data Array elements are:\n";

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        cout << data[i] << "     ";
    }

    cout << endl;

    return;
}


static void SwapIntPtr(int**a, int**b)
{
    int* temp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = temp;
    return;
}

static void Sorting(int* ptrarr[], int size)
{

        for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < size - i - 1; j++)
            {
                if (*ptrarr[j] > *ptrarr[j + 1])
                {
                    SwapIntPtr(&ptrarr[j], &ptrarr[j + 1]);
                }
            }
        }
        
        return;

}

int main()
{
    int size=9;
    int data[] = { 9, 3, 6, 2, 8, 17, 42, 1, 7 };
    int * ptrarr[9];

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        ptrarr[i] = &data[i];
    }

    Sorting(ptrarr, size);
    DisplayData( data, size );
    DisplayArray( ptrarr, size );
}
```

However, you don't even need that much.  The standard library includes a perfectly functional `sort` routine that can handle your array:

```
    sort( begin(ptrarr), end(ptrarr), [](int * p1, int * p2){return *p1 < *p2;});
```

Output for both:

```
Data Array elements are:
9     3     6     2     8     17     42     1     7     
The Pointer Array of sorted pointer elements:
1     2     3     6     7     8     9     17     42
```

Comment: It also has a perfectly reasonable `swap` function if for some reason you wanted to do your own sorting algo.